# How can I add items to the output file?

Tags: c++

I am a newbie to C++ and I've got my first assignment. We've got a text file that contains 5 employee names, wages, and hours worked.

And this is my code so that my program could read it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream input;
    ofstream output;

    string name;
    int h;
    float w;
    int numEployee = 0;
    double maxPay, minPay, avgPay;
    int gross, adjGross;

    //input/output file document path
    input.open("/Users/jmduller/Documents/xcode/Lab1/Lab1/Employees.txt");
    output.open("/Users/jmduller/Documents/xcode/Lab1/Lab1/Employeesoutput.txt");

    //checks if the input file is working
    if (input.fail())
    {
        cout << "Input file failed to open." << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }

    //checks if output file is working
    if (output.fail())
    {
        cout << "Output file failed to open." << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }

    //prints the name, wage, hours worked of the employees to the output file
    while (input >> name >> w >> h)
    {
        output << setw(5) << name << setw(5) << w << setw(5) << h << endl;
    }


  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

It's reading it properly and giving me the output file that I want but there are missing items. The complete output file should be have the number of employees, max pay, min pay, avg pay, gross pay, and adjusted gross.

Can anyone help me point to the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Here are the directions you need to create a [mcve]. Simply ask yourself the following question: can someone take all the information you gave in your question, and reproduce your problem, themselves? If not, then your question fails to meet all the requirements for a [mcve].

Comment: well, your `while` loop reads 3 tokens and passes them to output file. Why did you expect something else to apprear there? You mention **avg pay** - where are you calculating it?

Comment: You're making no effort to write any of that information. You have a comment that says it does, but you've not added that to the code in that block. If you do so, you won't have the problem any longer. We're not doing your homework for you. If you want those items in your output, then change the code to include them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you got to do is use some conditions and statements inside your while loop statement (which is reading from the file). Increment your 'numEmployee' variable everytime the loop executes(counts number of entries).

compare the 'w' read to check if it is lower than than the minPay(initialized to something very large) then update minPay otherwise if higher than maxPay(intialized to the  least value possible) update maxPay.

Also, add the 'w' to another variable sumPay(initialized to zero) in loop and at the end divide it by numEmployee and you are done. 
Just output them into the file before return statement.